# for loop and applying condition to ignore limited data

Tags: r, loops

I have a data.frame in this format

```
     data.frame':   566171 obs. of  10 variables:
     $ id    : Factor w/ 120 levels "2200100","2200200",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ year  : int  1950 1950 1950 1950 1950 1950 1950 1950 1950 1950 ...
     $ yday  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
     $ date  : Date, format: "1950-01-01" "1950-01-02" ...
     $ t_max : atomic  -17.2 -23.9 -25 -22.8 -19.4 -19.4 -11.1 -15.6 -17.8 -20.6 ...
     ..- attr(*, "long.name")= chr "daily maximum temperature"
     ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "°C"
      $ rain  : atomic  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     ..- attr(*, "long.name")= chr "total rainfall"
      ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mm"
```

I wrote the following loop to subset the data:

```
    library (seas)

    uniq <- unique(unlist(mdata$id))
    for (i in 1: length(uniq)){
      data_1 <- subset(mdata, id == uniq[i])
      d1 <-mksub(data_1) 
      year.plot(mksub(d1))
    }
```

It works well to a point, however, the loop stops running when station id do not have sufficient data. How can I tell R within my loop to ignore station id that do not have sufficient data to apply year.plot function and continue with other station until the final id?

Comment: You probably want something involving an `if` conditional and a `next` statement. See here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Thomas laid out what you should be doing in general. Let me see if I can put that together for you. I am going to use mscdata from the seas package, and assume that anything less than 2 is insufficient

```
library(seas)

data(mscdata)

uniq <- unique(unlist(mscdata$id))


for (i in 1: length(uniq)){
  data_1 <- subset(mscdata, id == uniq[i])
  try(if(length(data_1) < 2) {
    next
  } else {
    d1 <-mksub(data_1) 
    year.plot(mksub(d1))
  })
}
```

This reproducible example should work for you.

Comment: thanks guys this didnt help me...got error Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level...

Comment: I made a syntactical error which I fixed, however that may not solve your problem. A sample of your dataset, so that the problem is reproducible, would help as well.

Comment: I tried to reproduce a part of your dataset and got a strange error, so I also added try. See if my edit works now.

Comment: id year yday       date t_max t_min t_mean rain snow precip
1  2200100 1950    1 1950-01-01 -17.2 -28.9  -23.1    0  0.0    0.0
2  2200100 1950    2 1950-01-02 -23.9 -31.7  -27.8    0  0.0    0.0
....

Comment: no it didnt work ..if my sample data is confusing , the you see some from the seas package

Comment: fname <- system.file("extdata", "A1128551.DLY", package="seas")
dat <- read.msc(fname)

Comment: Check my edit. I used a dataset from the seas package and was able to get a reproducible example.